# How can I calculate the new cursor position relative to my canvas after zooming in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

**Context:**

I try to create a coloring pixels game with Canvas.
As of right now, I render a few rects via `strokeRect` that can be painted onClick via `fillRect`.

Since the canvas is not full screen but just a fixed size I need to calculate the offset. When I have the coordinates I just divide the x with the rect width (10).

Here is the code I have.

First I get the correct cursor position:

```
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    const x = event.clientX - rect.left
    const y = event.clientY - rect.top

   
    return { x: x, y: y };
  }
```

Then I will calculate where to `fillRect`so it seems that I filled the `strokeRect` on exactly that position:

```
const paint = (e, isClick) => {
    if (!isDrawing && !isClick) {
      return;
    }

    const coordinates = getCursorPosition(canvas, e);

    let rectX = Math.floor(coordinates.x / 10);
    let rectY = Math.floor(coordinates.y / 10);
    // stop drawing when it's outside of the bounds (i have a grid 100 x 100)
    if (rectX > 99 || rectY > 99) {
      return;
    }

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(rectX * 10, rectY * 10, 10, 10);
  };
```

**The Problem:**

So that works like a charm. But today I installed `React-zoom-pan-pinch`

Obviously, after I zoom into the canvas everything is messed up since the `getCursorPosition` function has to do more work. I need to calculate the new correct position after zooming. But I can't figure out how.

So after I zoom in and I click on the rects (pixels), the colored rect appears on the far right and far bottom. So it's very off right now.

The package gives me this function `onZoom` that gets these parameters: `ReactZoomPanPinchRef` and `event`. These have many attributes on them for example `x`, `y`, `offsetX`, .. and many more.

I tried several combinations but I can't get it to work.

**The question:**

How can I calculate the new Cursor Position relative to my Canvas so I can draw rectangles over it? What is the calculation I need to make given all the attributes that the `onZoom` event/props give me.

Here are all the attributes from this package:

https://prc5.github.io/react-zoom-pan-pinch/?path=/story/docs-props--page

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a list of props that `ReactZoomPanPinchRef` and `event` gives me. I could make screenshots but it's a long list.

**What I found out so far:**

I found a react drawing boar repo made with react + canvas.
He uses a mousewheel function which you can see here:

https://github.com/dilidili/react-drawing-board/blob/master/src/SketchPad.tsx#L858

Also this matrix I could locate here:

https://github.com/dilidili/react-drawing-board/blob/master/src/utils.ts#L4

Never heard of that. But maybe I need something like that.
Also the package `react-zoom-pan-pinch` provides in the `onZoom` function this parameter:

`ReactZoomPanPinchRef` that has state on it that looks like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k7hc.jpg

So I went back and tried this out like so:

```
 let rectX = Math.floor((coordinates.x + zoomState.offsetX) / rectSize);
    let rectY = Math.floor((coordinates.y + zoomState.offsetY) / rectSize);
```

Now it's much better but the further I zoom in the worse it gets.

Last but not least, here is a codesandbox where you can try this all out:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-darkness-iqwku?file=/src/components/canvas.js:2023-2171

Relevant files: `index.js` + `components\canvas.js`

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thx guys appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it seems you've been fiddling with the offset of the zoom state. The offset however is perfectly captured by `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` as it still returns the position of the top left corner even after the CSS transform.

The problem lies in your conversion to the `rectX` and `rectY`: by zooming in or out the size of your rectangles change, which is not yet reflected in your calculations. The following snippet solves this issue:

```
const scale = zoomState?.scale ?? 1;
let rectX = Math.floor(coordinates.x / (rectSize * scale));
let rectY = Math.floor(coordinates.y / (rectSize * scale));
```

A working example can be witnessed in [this fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-morning-tcspp) of your CodeSandbox.

Comment: As an added unrelated bonus tip, `return { x: x, y: y }` can be written as `return { x, y }`. When the variable you want to use as a value in your newly created object has the same name as the desired key, you can write it like this.

Comment: Yep `return { x, y }` I knew about. I was just sloppy with that one :D Thx again